# How to handle passing field values when immediate attribute is used in commandButton

Tags: apex, validation, commandbutton, inputfield

I have a situation in my code where I need to validate input fields when a user clicks the "Save" button. I have other commandButtons on the page, one specifically that copies the values of an existing set of fields into a new set that rerenders on the page (the button is called "Add row"). The problem I'm encountering is that if I use the immediate attribute on my commandButton, the values of the old set of fields are not copied. I know this is correct functionality, since the immediate attribute discards values from fields. So when the action of creating a new row/set of fields is done, the values are never set (I set these values in Apex btw).

My question is, is there a way to pass these values into Apex and still ignore validation when clicking on certain commandButtons? Will I have to do validation with JavaScript to bypass this? Or will I have to validate in the Apex code so that validation is only done when accessing the save method? Ideally, I would like to not lose the visual validation (red font and error message) that comes by default on required inputFields.

Here is the code for your reference:

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="MultiNewMemberForm_Controller" tabstyle="Case">
   <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, '/bootstrap-4.0.0-    alpha.6-dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css')}"/>
   <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MultiNewMemberForm_Styles)}"/>
     <apex:form id="theForm">
   <div class="MultiNewMember">
   <apex:pageBlock title="New Members" >
      <div class="row headers">
         <div class="col ident">
            <h4>Ident</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="col namefield">
         </div>
         <div class="col permissionselector">
            <h4>Permission Set</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="col emailtypedd">
            <h4>Welcome Email</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="col invitationdatepicker">
            <h4>Invitation Date</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="col actionbtn">
            <h4>Action</h4>
         </div>
      </div>
      <apex:repeat value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper">
         <div class="row fieldrow">
            <div class="col ident">
               <apex:outputText value="{!wrapper.ident}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col namefield">
               <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                  <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.curCase.Subject}"     label="Subject"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.curCase.ContactId}"     label="Name"/>
                  <apex:inputField value="{!wrapper.curCase.Profile__c}"     label="Profile"/>
               </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </div>
            <div class="col permissionselector">
               <apex:inputField value="    {!wrapper.curCase.Permission_Set__c}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col emailtypedd">
               <apex:inputField value="    {!wrapper.curCase.Welcome_Email__c}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col invitationdatepicker">
               <apex:inputField value="    {!wrapper.curCase.Invitation_Date__c}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col actionbtn">
               <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!delWrapper}"     rerender="theForm" immediate="true">
                  <apex:param name="toDelIdent" value="{!wrapper.ident}"     assignTo="{!toDelIdent}"/> 
               </apex:commandButton>
            </div>
         </div>
      </apex:repeat>
      <apex:commandButton value="Add Row" action="{!addRows}"     rerender="theForm">
         <apex:param name="addCount" value="1" assignTo="{!addCount}"/> 
      </apex:commandButton>
      <apex:commandButton value="Add 5 Rows" action="{!addRows}"     rerender="theForm">
         <apex:param name="addCount" value="5" assignTo="{!addCount}"/> 
      </apex:commandButton>
      <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   </div>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class MultiNewMemberForm_Controller {
 @AuraEnabled public List<CaseWrapper> wrappers {get; set;}
 @AuraEnabled public static Integer toDelIdent {get; set;}
 @AuraEnabled public static Integer addCount {get; set;}
 private Integer nextIdent=0;

 public MultiNewMemberForm_Controller()
 {
   wrappers=new List<CaseWrapper>();
   for (Integer idx=0; idx<1; idx++)
   {
     wrappers.add(new CaseWrapper(nextIdent++));
   }
 }

 public void delWrapper()
 {
   Integer toDelPos=-1;
    Integer wrapCount = wrappers.size();
   for (Integer idx=0; idx<wrappers.size(); idx++)
   {
     if (wrappers[idx].ident==toDelIdent)
     {
       toDelPos=idx;
     }
   }

   if (-1!=toDelPos)
   {
     wrappers.remove(toDelPos);
   }

    for (Integer idx=0; idx<wrappers.size(); idx++)
    {
        wrappers[idx].ident=idx + 1;
    }

    nextIdent = wrappers.size();
 }

 public void addRows()
 {
   Integer previousRow = wrappers.size()-1;

   for (Integer idx=0; idx<addCount; idx++)
   {
     wrappers.add(new CaseWrapper(nextIdent++));
     setNewRowValues(previousRow);
   }
 }

 private void setNewRowValues(Integer rowRef)
 {
   Integer lastRow = wrappers.size()-1;
    System.debug('rowRef: ' + rowRef);
    System.debug('lastRow: ' + lastRow);
   wrappers[1].curCase.Subject = wrappers[0].curCase.Subject;
   wrappers.get(lastRow).curCase.Profile__c =     wrappers.get(rowRef).curCase.Profile__c;
   wrappers.get(lastRow).curCase.Permission_Set__c =     wrappers.get(rowRef).curCase.Permission_Set__c;
   wrappers.get(lastRow).curCase.Welcome_Email__c =     wrappers.get(rowRef).curCase.Welcome_Email__c;
   wrappers.get(lastRow).curCase.Invitation_Date__c =     wrappers.get(rowRef).curCase.Invitation_Date__c;
    System.debug('Subject: ' + wrappers[0].curCase.Subject);
 }

 public PageReference save()
 {
   List<Case> caseList=new List<Case>();
   for (CaseWrapper wrap : wrappers)
   {
     caseList.add(wrap.curCase);
   }

   insert caseList;

   return new PageReference('/' +     Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Case').getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/o');
 }

 public class CaseWrapper
 {
   public Case curCase {get; private set;}
   public Integer ident {get; private set;}

   public CaseWrapper(Integer inIdent)
   {
      ident=inIdent + 1;
     Id recordTypeId = [Select Id from RecordType where Name = 'New Member'     and SobjectType = 'Case' LIMIT 1].Id;
     curCase = new Case(RecordTypeId = recordTypeId);
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Either you can validate fields on the controller side or use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only solution was to use a combination of JavaScript and Apex validation for the form. I had to not use the built-in validation for each inputField. Here is the code in case anybody wants to reference:

```
<apex:page controller="MultiNewMemberForm_Controller" tabstyle="Case">
   <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, '/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css')}"/>
   <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MultiNewMemberForm_Styles)}"/>
   <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery224}"/>

   <script>
  $(function() { requireNewFields(); });

  function requireNewFields() {
     $(".nameInput").each(function() {
        if(this.value == null || this.value == '') {
           this.classList.add("field-required");
        }
     });
     $(".profileDd").each(function() {
        if(this.value == null || this.value == '') {
           $(this).addClass("field-required");
        }
     });
     $(".emailDd").each(function() {
        if(this.value == null || this.value == '') {
           $(this).addClass("field-required");
        }
     });
     $(".dateInput").each(function() {
        if(this.value == null || this.value == '') {
           $(this).addClass("field-required");
        }
     });
  }

  function validateField(obj) {
     if(obj.value != '' && obj.value != null) {
        obj.classList.remove("field-required");
     }
     else if (!obj.classList.contains("field-required")) {
        obj.classList.add("field-required");
     }
  }
   </script>
   <apex:actionStatus id="checkNewFields" onstop="requireNewFields()" />
      <apex:form id="theForm">
         <apex:pagemessages />
         <div class="MultiNewMember">
            <apex:pageblock title="New Members">
               <div class="row headers">
                  <div class="col ident">
                     <h4>Ident</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col namefield">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col permissionselector">
                     <h4>Permission Set</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col emailtypedd">
                     <h4>Welcome Email</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col invitationdatepicker">
                     <h4>Invitation Date</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col actionbtn">
                     <h4>Action</h4>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <apex:repeat value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper">
                  <div class="row fieldrow">
                     <div class="col ident">
                        <apex:outputtext value="{!wrapper.ident}" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="col namefield">
                        <apex:pageblocksection columns="1">
                           <apex:inputfield value="{!wrapper.curCase.Subject}" label="Subject" />
                           <apex:inputfield value="    {!wrapper.curCase.ContactId}" label="Name" styleclass="nameInput" onblur="validateField(this)" />
                           <apex:inputfield value="{!wrapper.curCase.Profile__c}" label="Profile" styleclass="profileDd" onblur="validateField(this)" />
                        </apex:pageblocksection>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col permissionselector">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!wrapper.curCase.Permission_Set__c}" styleclass="permissionSet" onblur="validateField(this)" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="col emailtypedd">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!wrapper.curCase.Welcome_Email__c}" styleclass="emailDd" onblur="validateField(this)" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="col invitationdatepicker">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!wrapper.curCase.Invitation_Date__c}" styleclass="dateInput" onblur="validateField(this)" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="col actionbtn">
                        <apex:commandbutton value="Delete" action="{!delWrapper}" rerender="theForm" status="checkNewFields">
                           <apex:param name="toDelIdent" value="{!wrapper.ident}" assignto="{!toDelIdent}" />
                        </apex:commandbutton>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </apex:repeat>
               <apex:commandbutton value="Add Row" action="{!addRows}" rerender="theForm" status="checkNewFields">
                  <apex:param name="addCount" value="1" assignto="{!addCount}" />
               </apex:commandbutton>
               <apex:commandbutton value="Add 5 Rows" action="{!addRows}" rerender="theForm" status="checkNewFields">
                  <apex:param name="addCount" value="5" assignto="{!addCount}" />
               </apex:commandbutton>
               <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
            </apex:pageblock>
         </div>
      </apex:form>
</apex:page>

public with sharing class MultiNewMemberForm_Controller {
 public List<CaseWrapper> wrappers {get; set;}
 public static Integer toDelIdent {get; set;}
 public static Integer addCount {get; set;}
 private Integer nextIdent=0;

 public MultiNewMemberForm_Controller()
 {
   wrappers=new List<CaseWrapper>();
   for (Integer idx=0; idx<1; idx++)
   {
     wrappers.add(new CaseWrapper(nextIdent++));
   }
 }

 public void delWrapper()
 {
   Integer toDelPos=-1;
    Integer wrapCount = wrappers.size();
   for (Integer idx=0; idx<wrappers.size(); idx++)
   {
     if (wrappers[idx].ident==toDelIdent)
     {
       toDelPos=idx;
     }
   }

   if (-1!=toDelPos)
   {
     wrappers.remove(toDelPos);
   }

    for (Integer idx=0; idx<wrappers.size(); idx++)
    {
        wrappers[idx].ident=idx + 1;
    }

    nextIdent = wrappers.size();
 }

 public void addRows()
 {
   Integer previousRow = wrappers.size()-1;

   for (Integer idx=0; idx<addCount; idx++)
   {
     wrappers.add(new CaseWrapper(nextIdent++));
     setNewRowValues(previousRow);
   }
 }

 private void setNewRowValues(Integer rowRef)
 {
   Integer lastRow = wrappers.size()-1;
   wrappers[lastRow].curCase.Subject = wrappers[rowRef].curCase.Subject;
   wrappers[lastRow].curCase.Profile__c =     wrappers[rowRef].curCase.Profile__c;
   wrappers[lastRow].curCase.Permission_Set__c = wrappers[rowRef].curCase.Permission_Set__c;
   wrappers[lastRow].curCase.Welcome_Email__c = wrappers[rowRef].curCase.Welcome_Email__c;
   wrappers[lastRow].curCase.Invitation_Date__c =     wrappers[rowRef].curCase.Invitation_Date__c;
 }

 public PageReference save()
 {
    // PageReference saveCompletePage = new PageReference('/' + Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Case').getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/o');
    PageReference saveCompletePage = new PageReference('/500?fcf=00Bn0000000uzFI');

    if (verifyFields())
    {
       List<Case> caseList=new List<Case>();
        for (CaseWrapper wrap : wrappers)
        {
        caseList.add(wrap.curCase);
        }

        insert caseList;
    }
    else
    {
        saveCompletePage = new PageReference('/apex/MultiNewMemberForm');
        saveCompletePage.setRedirect(false);
    }

    return saveCompletePage;
 }

 private Boolean verifyFields()
 {
    Boolean formVerified = true;

    for (Integer idx=0; idx<wrappers.size(); idx++)
    {
        Integer lineNumber = idx + 1;
        if (wrappers[idx].curCase.ContactId == null)
        {
            formVerified = false;
            validatorMsgGenerator('Name', lineNumber);
        }

        if (wrappers[idx].curCase.Profile__c == null)
        {
            formVerified = false;
            validatorMsgGenerator('Profile', lineNumber);
        }

        if (wrappers[idx].curCase.Permission_Set__c == null)
        {
            formVerified = false;
            validatorMsgGenerator('Permission Set', lineNumber);
        }

        if (wrappers[idx].curCase.Welcome_Email__c == null)
        {
            formVerified = false;
            validatorMsgGenerator('Welcome Email', lineNumber);
        }

        if (wrappers[idx].curCase.Invitation_Date__c == null)
        {
            formVerified = false;
            validatorMsgGenerator('Invitation Date', lineNumber);
        }
}

    return formVerified;
 }

 private void validatorMsgGenerator(String label, Integer lineNumber)
 {
    String errorMsg = 'Error: ' + label + ' missing on line ' + lineNumber;
    ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, errorMsg);
   ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
 }

 public class CaseWrapper
 {
   public Case curCase {get; private set;}
   public Integer ident {get; private set;}

   public CaseWrapper(Integer inIdent)
   {
      ident=inIdent + 1;
     Id recordTypeId = [Select Id from RecordType where Name = 'New Member' and SobjectType = 'Case' LIMIT 1].Id;
     curCase = new Case(RecordTypeId = recordTypeId);
   }
 }
}
```

Also, if anybody has a better solution, by all means please post it.